# Linux mint 17.1 libgtk

Tags: command-line, gnome, dependencies

Hi i have problem while i want install gnome shell in linux mint ,iam using this command:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool

and its display this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-shell : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.11.1) but 3.10.8~8+qiana is to be installed
gnome-tweak-tool : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (>= 3.12) but 3.10.8~8+qiana is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I cant install newer verision of libgtk.

Please help me how to install gnome shell!

Thanks!

[Sory for my english]

Comment: Questions about Linux Mint should be asked on [unix.se].

Comment: If you would like to try **Gnome Shell**, it would be easier to go this way: http://ubuntugnome.org -- especially considering that Ubuntu is based on Debian and Gnome, with Unity Desktop Environment, and Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, with Cinnamon Desktop Environment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1829) at Linux Mint Community:

> "Gnome isn't extremely compatible with Linux Mint. It works but other operating systems probably work better. Ubuntu 14.04 for example. You can even download a gnome version for it. http://ubuntugnome.org/ Another operating system that is gnome-based is Fedora.
>
> Also, I haven't managed to install extensions other than the ones through terminal below. I'm guessing it is possible but extra complicated than in the original gnome version.
>
> Personally, I've removed gnome again, for now. I liked it, but it just isn't as compatible as I'd want it to be... By the way, when I installed gnome I installed it alongside cinnamon; I did not remove cinnamon."

It is really necessary to install the gnome shell on your Mint build? It seems like the pain is not worth it.

Comment: I was tried Ubuntu gnome a several months ago and all the time lags in the installation : (